# Removing the Last word from TextView using Speech Recognition

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm building an app using speech recognition.. I'm storing the last sentence in a string from the textView and trying to compare it with the new word spoken like, when the User say "remove" the last word from the string in the text View should be removed..

I don't know what is wrong with this code ..

```
if(requestCode == request_code && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        if(matches != null && matches.size() > 0)
        {
            text = matches.get(0);
            if(text == "hello")
            {
                text = (String) et.getText();
                rep = text.replaceAll("\\d+\\Z", "");

                Log.d(tag, "THis is not working");
                et.setText(rep);
                rep = null;

            }
            else
            {
            option = matches.get(0);
            et.setText(option);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance :D

Comment: How does the code behave right now, are there exceptions? Or is it not finding any matches? Please let us know what is happening

Comment: Sir I want to remove the last word when the user say "hello" , like a backspace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if(text.equals("hello"))` instead of `if(text == "hello")`

or perhaps even better: `if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))`

---

remove last word from a text area:

```
String text = textArea.getText();

// capture everything except the last word into group 1
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\w+\\s*\\Z", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(text);

if (matcher.find()) {
    text = matcher.group(1);
    textArea.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.. my problem is solved almost.. But can you help me with the rest of the code.. I'm still having that problem...